# Where is the documentation for launch.json parameters

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

"preLaunchTask": "npm: compile" for example. I am working in Java. Is there a "java: compile"? Am I expected to find the code and read it? I search in GitHub and I find a usage of it: https://github.com/search?l=&q=preLaunchTask+language%3AJava&type=Code

I was looking for documentation for all the fun things I might want to do with launch.json.

When I search Google I keep ending up on the vscode hello world page or whatever that is explaining how simple everything is to, I am not sure what, "get started"?

I am most interested in the exact details of everything contained in this:

your hlq /.vscode/extensions/ask-toolkit.alexa-skills-kit-toolkit-1.0.1/.vscode$

// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387

I follow the suggested link and there is a lot of general information with more links to more information and examples, mainly for node. Is that how it works in 2019?

I was looking for "preLaunchTask is a key:value specification."
    Valid values for key npm are...
                        java are...
                          js are...
                        ruby are...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which debugger you are using.

> Note that the attributes available in launch configurations vary from
> debugger to debugger. You can use IntelliSense suggestions
> (Ctrl+Space) to find out which attributes exist for a specific
> debugger. Hover help is also available for all attributes.
>
> Do not assume that an attribute that is available for one debugger
> automatically works for other debuggers too. If you see green
> squiggles in your launch configuration, hover over them to learn what
> the problem is and try to fix them before launching a debug session.

- from [launch configurations](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations).

The debugger for Java that you are using should provide information about its specific options.  For example, [java debugger](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-debug) lists many options.

In addition, there are a few launch attributes, like `preLaunchTask` that are provided by vscode and either mandatory or available in all launch configs.  For their descriptions, see [launch.json attributes](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_launchjson-attributes):

> Here are some optional attributes available to all launch
> configurations:
>
> preLaunchTask - to launch a task before the start of a debug session,
> set this attribute to the name of a task specified in tasks.json (in
> the workspace's .vscode folder).
>
> postDebugTask - to launch a task at the very end of a debug session,
> set this attribute to the name of a task specified in tasks.json (in
> the workspace's .vscode folder).
>
> internalConsoleOptions - this attribute controls the visibility of the
> Debug Console panel during a debugging session.
>
> debugServer - for debug extension authors only: this attribute allows
> you to connect to a specified port instead of launching the debug
> adapter.
>
> serverReadyAction - if you want to open a URL in a web browser
> whenever the program under debugging outputs a specific message to the
> debug console or integrated terminal. For details see section
> Automatically open a URI when debugging a server program below.

and more are listed at that last link.

Comment: Thank you Mark, that actually helps. So depending on where you are and what you are running information may be offered about something in the context one is in. Not much help for someone that knows the concept, knows exactly what they want to do and is looking for the exact syntax to make it so; but I get it, that is not available. I had read this "The most important key combination to know is Ctrl+Shift+P" some days ago and I found it again tonight after I read this "Discover ASK commands by typing “ASK” from the VS Code command palette"... there is hope!